# Database replication without duplicating IDs when sync

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, database-design, architecture

I need to replicate my database to more than one location around the world. I have tested the SQL Server replication successfully, but the database I need to replicate has a table that gives unique ids for all the other tables.

Example of the issue
I have a Spain location (slave location) and a US location (main location) both that the exact same database schema which include the table that generates unique ids for all the other tables. when a record in Span in created it has an unique id for example 123 then, when the sync tries to happen, id 123 was already created in my US location and the latest unique id is 311.

So my question is how would SQL Server replication need to be configure to support such a paradigm?

Comment: Ids like this always tend to give you a big headache in replication scenarios, if possible I would strongly recommend switching all relevant ids to the type UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

Comment: Use a composite key. One attribute is the id, the other identifies the node which originated that id. The combination is therefore unique.

Comment: I deleted my answer as I misread the question. If you are worried about unique key clashes like this then perhaps you can generate a certain range of values form each instance (feels like a hack to me). Another options would be to use timestamps or unique identifier as a ROWGUIDCOL to ensure uniqueness across instances. You would be best served using merge replication in this scenario as opposed to transactional replication as I stated earlier.

Comment: @MichaelSander  switching all relevant ids to uniqueidentifier type will no work because "business politics" "That's how ids have being done for the last 20 year, it's proven that it works"

Comment: A composite key might be the solution based on my previous comment.

Comment: @VictorAChavez Aye, business politics is one of the harder bugs to fix... :) How about keeping the old Primary Key and just adding a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, calling int ReplicationId? That way you serve the politicians, and have great replication support. I tend to have both anyway, an INT primary key and an additional UNIQIUEIDENTIFIER key. Using UIDs only has some drawbacks as well...